# Resize images tinypng salesforce

Tags: rest, api, web-services, salesforce, apex

I have a question about the images exchange between salesforce and an image compression API (tinyPng). Can we use a REST webservice to send images uploaded with (lightning uploadfile) to the API (tinyPng). And rreturn the compressed image. And replace the original image in salesforce with a compressed image. If anyone can give me track, solutions I will be delighted grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger on that purpose. 
Put it on the file creation and then use the data stored to call your rest API to call that webservice.

If you want an app that is already mastering the image size and format you can also rely on SharinPix from the AppExchange.